# CrudRepository - delete by Date

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, crud, sql-delete

Could you please help me with the following problem?

I have an Entity:

```
@Entity
public class Logging {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "domain")
    private String domain;

    @Column(name = "time_stamp")
    private Date timeStamp;
```

I have also:

```
public interface LoggingRepository extends CrudRepository<Logging, Integer> {

    // @Query("Delete from Logging l WHERE l.timeStamp < ?1 AND l.domain =?2")
    void deleteLoggingTimeStampBeforeAndByDomain(Date timeStamp, String domain);
}
```

Using `CrudRepository` I want to delete Logging records that are less than dateX and Logging.domain = myDomain. Something like:

```
DELETE from Logging l WHERE l.time_stamp < '2018-05-22 21:32:26' AND l.domain = 'abc.com'.
```

In database column `time_stamp` looks like `2018-05-22 21:32:26`

In my MySQL table Logging `time_stamp` is of type TIMESTAMP.

I use Spring Boot. Actually I get the following error:

> There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error,
>   status=500). Parameter value [2018-05-22 21:32:36.0] did not match
>   expected type [java.lang.String (n/a)]; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [2018-05-22
>   21:32:36.0] did not match expected type [java.lang.String (n/a)]
>
> EDIT: When I chang emy method to:

```
 @Query("Delete from Logging l WHERE timeStamp < :timeStamp AND domain =:domain")
    void deleteLoggingTimeStampBeforeAndByDomain(@Param("timeStamp") Date timeStamp, @Param("domain") String domain);
```

I get the error:

> org.hibernate.hql.internal.QueryExecutionRequestException: Not
>   supported for DML operations [Delete from
>   entity.Logging l WHERE timeStamp < :timeStamp AND
>   domain =:domain]

Do you have any idea? I've spent many hours but unfortunately without success.
I've tried with `@Query` and special naming convention without `@Query`.

Answer (score 0):

OK, **I have the solution:** I had to add @Modifying just like:

```
@Modifying
@Query("Delete from Logging l WHERE timeStamp < :timeStamp AND domain =:domain")
    void deleteLoggingTimeStampBeforeAndByDomain(@Param("timeStamp") Date timeStamp, @Param("domain") String domain);
```

Sorry for all the fuss.

Thank you.
Matley